# Adaptive card image not rendering on Microsoft Teams using MS Flow

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to post an adaptive card on channel of MS Teams using MS Flow,
it is loading fine but only the issue is that this adaptive card also contains image which is not rendering on Teams. It works fine in **Adaptive Card designer**.

[Working on Adaptive Card Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtsQv.png)

But not rendering in teams
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1XmQ.png)

```
 {
"type": "Image",
"altText":"ok",
"separator":true,
"height":"18px",
"url": "https://adaptivecards.io/content/cats/1.png"

},
```

[url issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbm7h.png)

Comment: Did you got a solution to this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes i got the solution. I just changed my network connection. :D

Comment: Will it means some image will not work in some network connection?
Any proper solution?